# Is there built-in functionality in django to make inline editing (admin side) objects?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Editing objects of one model (not as shown in [the example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial07/), inline that has relation to the other model)?

[image]

I want the same as on the picture above but to edit the objects of one model, no related ones...

Any suggestions, or I have to customise admin template?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do, but I think you might be looking for the [`list_editable`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_editable) option.

Comment: @Alasdair, yes that's it! Thanks, write as an answer! Now I have an other problem, i want to add button "Add extra fields" (to not open new page for adding a new item), is it possible?

Comment: I do not understand what you want the button to do. It sounds like a separate problem.

Comment: @Alasdair For example, I need to add manufacturers of cars, with few fields... (name, country, maybe sth else). So, I dont want to open separate page for each, but want to do as a list

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you're hoping for.

Comment: @Alasdair all right, probably my explanation is not so clear. As shown on the picture above, there are choices for the poll, that can be added dynamically.... (without opening the pages of each choice)...there is a button "Add another choice", which adds empty rows above to fill in.. I want the same, but "extra" parameter doesn't work

Comment: There was a ticket [#11574](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11574) to allow extra blank rows when using `list_editable`, but it was closed as wontfix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`list_editable`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_editable) option allows you to edit fields on the changelist page.